# PHP Sort activities into the correct array based on their date

Tags: php, arrays, date

I am trying to sort an array of activities based on their dates. For example:

- "Do stuff" 2020-06-06
- "Do more stuff" 2020-06-06
- "Do even more" 2020-06-07

I now want to place these dates into a new array specifically for one date so an array for 2020-06-06 and an array for 2020-06-07 but the dates differ everytime so there it is no possible to make predifined arrays.

```
activityArray = CMS_GetActivity("1");
$activityList = array();

foreach ($activityArray as $tempActivity) {

   array_push($activityList, $tempActivity);
}
$_SESSION['days'] = $activityList;
```

This is where i am now but I'm nowhere near where I wanted to be.

Comment: Can you add a `print_r` of the `$activityArray`? Am right in thinking you want to end up with an array like this
`[

    '2020-06-06' => [

      'Do Stuff',
      'Do other stuff',

    ]

]
`

Comment: Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [VolunteerId] => 1
            [ActivityId] => 3
            [Time] => 2020-06-06 10:42:00
            [Location] => geen idee
            [Description] => nog meer dingen doen
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [VolunteerId] => 1
            [ActivityId] => 1
            [Time] => 2020-06-06 12:30:00
            [Location] => PatronaatStraat 8
            [Description] => Tafels rechtzetten, stoelen weghalen. aanwezig bij: Patronaatstraat 58a 

        )
)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function GetActivity2(){
    //get all activities from the database belonging to the volunteer
    $activityArray = CMS_GetActivity("1");
    //make an array for all the days
    $dayList = array();

    //foreach activity from the database
    foreach ($activityArray as $tempActivity){
      //set a success meter on fail.
      //this success meter is set to success if the activity can be sorted in a day,
      //if the activivty can not be classified, the success stays on fail a new day is made.
      $sucessBool = false;

      //for every day in the daylist
      for ($i=0; $i < count($dayList); $i++) {
        //if the day is not empty
        if($dayList[$i] != NULL){
          //grab one activity from the daylist
          foreach ($dayList[$i] as $key) {
            //if the date corresponds with the date from the activity gotten from the database
            if (date("m-d-Y",strtotime($key->Time)) == date("m-d-Y",strtotime($tempActivity->Time))){
              //place the activity in that day
              array_push($dayList[$i], $tempActivity);
              //and set the success meter on success
              $sucessBool = true;
              //break out of the loop so only one activity of the day has to be checked
              break;
            }
            //break out of the loop to check for days
            break;
          }
        }
      }

      //check if the success meter is on Fail
      if($sucessBool == false){
        //empty an array
        $activityList = array();
        //put the activity in the activitylist
        array_push($activityList, $tempActivity);
        //put the activitylist in the daylist
        array_push($dayList, $activityList);
      }
    }
    $_SESSION['days'] = $dayList;
  }
```

This is my completed code, it is probably not the cleanest code but i'm fine with that.